# How to change WCF contract name?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

From the host project, where do I change the contract name being used by a WCF Service?  I've right clicked on the service reference in the project and selected properties, this only shows a folder name.  I've gone into Configure Service but there isn't anything about the contract there.

When I show all files in the project and open the service then Reference.svcmap > Reference.cs, about mid way down, I see:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://mysite.com/services/", ConfigurationName="MyServiceReference.IMyService")]
public interface IMyService {
```

ConfigurationName is the contract name that appears in the app.config/web.config.  But this is probably not the correct place to update it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your ConfigurationName where you have your service defined.  Just as it is in the map:

```
[ServiceContract(ConfigurationName="NewName")]
public interface IMyService {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I do not see [ServiceContract(ConfigurationName=" anywhere in the project.  Which file are you referring to?

Comment: ServiceContract should be an attribute on the interface in your WCF service. The ConfigurationName probably isn't set on it. He's suggesting you set it there.

Comment: Do you have [ServiceContract] anywhere in the project?  Can you show some source code of where you have your Service Contract Interface defined?

Comment: I don't have the text you've shown.  Only what I posted above, which I believe is the same as yours, except mine is System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace=

Comment: Is this your own service or are you using someone else's service?

Comment: Someone else's service (within the same company but I don't have source code).